# Como criar paleta de cores no MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, processamento-de-imagens

Como eu faço uma paleta de cores no MATLAB? Eu só quero a paleta, como na imagem, e não gráficos ou coisas do tipo....

[image: Paleta RGB]

Comment: Olá David. Você já tentou alguma estratégia? Já estudou algum material disponível na web? Normalmente a comunidade do StackOverflow aceita melhor as perguntas que demonstram um certo esforço anterior. Sugiro adicionar este tipo de informação na pergunta: Preciso disso, já tentei isso e isso, mas o resultado não está legal por aquilo outro.

Answer (score 2):

Como foi comentado em sua pergunta, seria bom você ter tentado algo, ou ter trazido opções, que existem varias. Vão algumas dicas para você desenvolver seu trabalho, qualquer coisa você retorna o código caso não consiga fazer. Pra fazer isso eu conheço três formas:

1. Criar uma figura, colocar o colour pallete na horizontal e esconder a figura. Ai você edita o titulo e escolhe a configuração de cores como quiser.
2. Usar o cbrewer do FileExchange, muito bom para criar o que você quer, e é o que uso atualmente.
3. Tambem disponível no FileExchange (pessoalmente gosto do anterior) o ColorBrewer também possibilita criar muitos colormaps customizados.

Uma quarta opção é você fazer seu código com o que o matlab tem disponivel que não é pouco e não é difícil, caso não consiga posta o código que nos ajudamos. Links abaixo:

[Trabalhar com colormap](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colormap.html)

[ColorBrewer](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/45208-colorbrewer--attractive-and-distinctive-colormaps)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[cbrewer](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/34087-cbrewer---colorbrewer-schemes-for-matlab)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]